# perl-Gtk2 How to identify if a widget is shown in current ScrolledWindow

Tags: perl, gtk2

I have a scrolled window with several widgets inside a HBox, I'm looking for a way to identify which widgets are currently shown in the ScrolledWindow view

Below code addes a 100 expanded items to a ScrolledWindow, I'm looking for a way to check if a spicific item is visible to the user and not outside the current view of the scrolled window.

Example Code:

```
my $ItemsCount = 100;                                            
my $ScWin  = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new(undef, undef);            
$ScWin->set_policy('automatic', 'automatic');                    
                                                                 
my $Frame      =  Gtk2::Frame->new('Items');                     
my  $ItemsBox   = Gtk2::Table->new(2, $ItemsCount+1, FALSE);      
                                                                 
my  $View = Gtk2::Viewport->new();                               
$View->add($ItemsBox);                                           
$ScWin->add($View);                                              
                                                                 
for my $i (0 .. $ItemsCount-1)  {                                
   my $exp =  Gtk2::Expander->new();                             
   $exp     ->set_label("Item #$i");                             
   $ItemsBox->attach($exp, 0, 1, $i, $i+1, 'fill', 'fill', 1, 2);
}                                                                
$MainBox    ->pack_start    ($ScWin     , TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

Comment: Please include a runnable code sample that illustrates the problem. See [mcve] for more information